# Redhat 5 Upgrade / Sphinx Search Init Startup Hangs

Tags: bash, redhat, init, sphinxsearch

I recently upgrade a VM to Redhat 5 and moved Sphinx Search to that server. For some reason when
I try to start Sphinx, the startup script fails to push the searchd process to the
background. I created a test script with a minimal version of the startup call, which is
as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
daemon /usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd --config
/home/app/code/server_config/sphinx_config.php
```

The searchd process starts and I get output that indicates it is listening on the correct
IP:port, but the process never returns.

The process that is hanging is in the daemon call, and ps shows it as:

```
/bin/bash -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd --config
/home/app/code/server_config/sphinx_config.php
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this or how to troubleshoot? We use the same process on about a dozen other
servers running Redhat 4 which work fine (although the process created by daemon uses initlog, so it is
different).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was nothing wrong with the init script, but that sphinx searchd was taking a very long time to start.  Insufficient memory was allocated on the VM, so it was having problems starting up with the large indexes.  Increased the memory allocation and works fine now.